# CentOs Dovecot won't start

Tags: centos, dovecot

Running `service dovecot status` reults as

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status dovecot.service
● dovecot.service - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dovecot.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:dovecot(1)
           http://wiki2.dovecot.org/

Feb 01 07:40:40 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
Feb 01 07:40:40 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: Job dovecot.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Feb 01 07:44:09 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
Feb 01 07:44:09 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: Job dovecot.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Feb 01 07:45:39 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
Feb 01 07:45:39 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: Job dovecot.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Feb 01 08:02:50 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
Feb 01 08:02:50 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: Job dovecot.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Feb 01 08:05:26 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
Feb 01 08:05:26 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: Job dovecot.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

Running `service dovecot start` results as

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start dovecot.service
A dependency job for dovecot.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
```

Running `journalctl -xe` results as

```
Feb 02 01:35:07 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: Can't open PID file /run/spamassassin.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Feb 02 01:35:07 xxxxx-vps.com spamd[44125]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 44126
Feb 02 01:35:07 xxxxx-vps.com spamd[44125]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 44127
Feb 02 01:35:07 xxxxx-vps.com spamd[44125]: prefork: child states: IS
Feb 02 01:35:07 xxxxx-vps.com spamd[44125]: prefork: child states: II
Feb 02 01:35:09 xxxxx-vps.com postfix/qmgr[44128]: fatal: qmgr_move: rename 5094B65FCC from active to incoming: No space left on deviceFeb 02 01:35:10 xxxxx-vps.com postfix/master[7434]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/qmgr pid 44128 exit status 1
Feb 02 01:35:10 xxxxx-vps.com postfix/master[7434]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/qmgr: bad command startup -- throttling
Feb 02 01:35:37 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency job for unit systemd-vconsole-setup.service, ignoring: Unit is masked. Feb 02 01:35:37 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: Starting One-time Dovecot init service...
-- Subject: Unit dovecot-init.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit dovecot-init.service has begun starting up.
Feb 02 01:35:37 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: dovecot-init.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Feb 02 01:35:37 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: Failed to start One-time Dovecot init service.
-- Subject: Unit dovecot-init.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit dovecot-init.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Feb 02 01:35:37 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
-- Subject: Unit dovecot.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit dovecot.service has failed.
--
-- The result is dependency.
Feb 02 01:35:37 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: Job dovecot.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Feb 02 01:35:37 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: Unit dovecot-init.service entered failed state.
Feb 02 01:35:37 xxxxx-vps.com systemd[1]: dovecot-init.service failed.
```

**Any suggestion?**

Comment: It says `No space left on device` right there in the log you quoted. I suggest you investigate whether you missed the time to provision more space, or whether someone is flooding your systems with junk.

Comment: @anx I managed to make it start again using [this article](https://www.osradar.com/how-to-install-dovecot-on-centos-8/)

Comment: If you solved the problem, it would help if you'd post that as an answer.

Comment: Agreed, but as solution is too long I shared link to it so people can read it themselves instead of I copy paste whole article here (doesn't make sense)